# File-ownership issues transitioning to new admin user (on same mac)

Tags: permission, user-account, migration

My single user (let's say `u0`) has over the years become cluttered.

I decided to create a new admin user `u1`, and incrementally migrate to it.

However I'm bumping into obstacles.

First up I'm switching `u1`'s shell to bash. So I want to `brew install bash` to get the latest (5.x).

```
> brew --version
Homebrew >=2.5.0 (shallow or no git repository)
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory 
:
```

I found a fix on SO:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
```

But now:

```
> brew install bash
Error: Can't create update lock in /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks!
Fix permissions by running:
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/var/homebrew
Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/usr/local/share/aclocal
/usr/local/share/doc
/usr/local/share/info
/usr/local/share/locale
/usr/local/share/man
/usr/local/share/man/man1
/usr/local/share/man/man3
/usr/local/share/man/man5
/usr/local/share/man/man7
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/var/homebrew/locks
/usr/local/var/log

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages /usr/local/share/aclocal /usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/info /usr/local/share/locale /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1 /usr/local/share/man/man3 /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks /usr/local/var/log

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages /usr/local/share/aclocal /usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/info /usr/local/share/locale /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1 /usr/local/share/man/man3 /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks /usr/local/var/log
```

yikes! So if I'm gona have to `chown` these `/usr/local/...` files to get `brew` to work, I'm worried (1) about messing up my original user, and (2) how much more tweaking I'm gona need before my `u1` is established as the new admin user (i.e. everything works) -- at which point I won't care if `u0` has issues.

How to play this? Options I see are:

1. Just give up on migrating `u0` -> `u1`, just tidy up `u0` as best I can
2. Keep pushing through, tweaking issues as they arise
3. pre-emptively `chown` the whole filesystem (or big chunks of it) to `u1`

Am I missing something?

Am I pushing a round peg into a square hole again?

EDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840479/how-to-use-homebrew-on-a-multi-user-macos-sierra-setup
^ This thread seems to cover all viable solution paths.
The only one that looks mathematcally clean to me is covered [here](https://www.codejam.info/2021/11/homebrew-multi-user.html).

Comment: Yes, as documented Homebrew is a single-user system.  There are kinda-sorta workarounds to use it in a multiuser environment, but they really just make Homebrew's basic security issue worse.

Comment: For a multi user system use macports or nix - they are based around normal Unix practices. Homebrew elevates one user to be the owner and installer and user.